# Node-Red custom node_modules location

Tags: node.js, npm, node-red, npm-link

I'm using node-red as embedded in my Express.js application like this
https://nodered.org/docs/embedding. When embedded like this node-red cant load new nodes from npm.

Issue is that when defining custom user dir in settings.js, for example `userDir: 'node-red-data/'` Node-red adds loaded nodes to this folder inside node_modules.

So I have two node_modules folder:

```
myapp/node_modules => this is containing node-red
myapp/node-red-data/node_modules => this is containing node-red extra nodes
```

Some how node-red can't load modules in side `myapp/node-red-data/node_modules`

Is there any solutions?

Comment: Can you create a minimal test case that shows the problem? Also what version of NodeJS, npm and Node-RED are you using?

Comment: Looks like the issue is Relative Paths. Still debbuing it, but changing userDir to absolutepath make things better.

Comment: Edit the question to include how you are creating the settings object

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Issue was on the settings file.

My setting in user dir:

```
var settings = {
    httpAdminRoot: '/admin',
    httpNodeRoot: '/ap',
    nodesDir: '/nodes',
    flowFile: "flows.json",
    userDir: './data/'
}
```

Right setup:

```
var path = require('path');
var dir = path.dirname(__filename);
var settings = {
    httpAdminRoot: '/admin',
    httpNodeRoot: '/ap',
    nodesDir: dir + '/nodes',
    flowFile: "flows.json",
    userDir: dir+'/data/'
}
```

So adding static path to user dir and nodes dir makes it working

Comment: working for me           var path = require('path');
var dir = path.dirname(__filename);
var settings = {
    httpAdminRoot: '/admin',
    httpNodeRoot: '/ap',
    flowFile: "flows.json",
    userDir: dir+'/data/'
}

Answer (score 0):

I have similar problem.
I used process.execPath

```
userdir = path.resolve(process.execPath,'..'); //better that __dirname;
```

Because the dir is diferent when application is compiled.

```
// Create the settings object - see default settings.js file for other options
var settings = {
    verbose: true,
    httpAdminRoot:"/admin",
    httpNodeRoot: "/",
    userDir: userdir, // problem with dir...
    flowFile: 'flows.json',
};
```